# in multiple checkbox , how store one answer JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

i have multiple question per page. the issue is if i answer first question , then when i check answer of second question , the first question's answer would be unchecked , my goal is for each question there would be only one answer and the answer will be stored.

---

```js
$('input.answer').on('change', function() {
    $('input.answer').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
$('input.answer').not(this).prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = "question">    
    
    
    <form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend for="0-0">my goal is having one answer per each question?to reporduce check three in first question and then check seven in second question , you would see the first question three would be unchecked which is not my desire</legend>
        <label for="0-0-4">one</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-0" type="checkbox" name="0-0-4" id="0-0-4" value="4">
        <label for="0-0-3">two</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-0" type="checkbox" name="0-0-3" id="0-0-3" value="3">
        <label for="0-0-2">three</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-0" type="checkbox" name="0-0-2" id="0-0-2" value="2">
        <label for="0-0-1">four</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-0" type="checkbox" name="0-0-1" id="0-0-1" value="1">
        <label for="0-0-0">five</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-0" type="checkbox" name="0-0-0" id="0-0-0" value="0">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    
    </div>
            <div class="question">


        <form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend for="1-0">this is second question but when i check any answer from first question then check one of the answer of second question , first question's answer will be uncheck which is undesired.</legend>
        <label for="0-1-4">six</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-1" type="checkbox" name="0-1-4" id="0-1-4" value="4">
        <label for="0-1-3">seven</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-1" type="checkbox" name="0-1-3" id="0-1-3" value="3">
        <label for="0-1-2">eight</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-1" type="checkbox" name="0-1-2" id="0-1-2" value="2">
        <label for="0-1-1">nine</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-1" type="checkbox" name="0-1-1" id="0-1-1" value="1">
        <label for="0-1-0">ten</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-1" type="checkbox" name="0-1-0" id="0-1-0" value="0">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
        <div class="question">
     <form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <legend for="1-1">to reporduce check three in first question and then check seven in second question , you would see the first question three would be unchecked which is not my desire</legend>
     <label for="1-1-4">eleven</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-4" type="checkbox" name="1-1-4" id="1-1-4" value="4">
        <label for="1-1-3">twelve</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-4" type="checkbox" name="1-1-3" id="1-1-3" value="3">
        <label for="1-1-2">thirteen</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-4" type="checkbox" name="1-1-2" id="1-1-2" value="2">
        <label for="1-1-1">fourteen</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-4" type="checkbox" name="1-1-1" id="1-1-1" value="1">
        <label for="1-1-0">fifteen</label>
        <input class="answer answer-num-4" type="checkbox" name="1-1-0" id="1-1-0" value="0">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jquery code, you have to indicate to work just with the fieldset of the selected checkbox...

```
$('input.answer').on('change', function() {

    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input.answer').not(this).prop('checked',false).checkboxradio("refresh");  

});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for answer , but with above code , its not possible to have only.one answer per each question , i mean i have tried your code in first question i can check one and two and three , my goal is having only one answer per question...

Comment: Is not his what you need  https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/tsfhbx6a/ ?
It's allowing me to check only one checkbox per section

Comment: doesn't work with jquery mobile , see here https://jsfiddle.net/e26n3v0w/9/

Comment: You'r right! Aparently, it doesn't like parent() function. 
I have edited the answer with a simplified and working code. Try that and let me know how it goes